# Impossibility to install keras in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to install `keras` in R according to the instructions in the documentation:

```
    install.packages('devtools')
    devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
```

But when I call `keras` the library:

```
    library(keras)
```

I get the following message:

> Error in library(keras) : there is no package called ‘keras’

What's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Check it's installed properly and in the same location as library is trying to load from

Comment: Read carefully the output of `devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")`. Look for error messages there

Comment: I got the following errors:     * ERROR: dependency 'tfruns' is not available for package 'keras'
* removing 'C:/Users/Win8/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/keras'
Error: Command failed (1)*

Comment: Are you really running R 3.2? That's a few years old now. Might want to try updating.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I installed a new version and now there is no problem. Thanks